# Подскажите логику выполнения кода - C#

Tags: c#, .net

Господа, доброго времени суток. Я закомментировал каждую строку, чтобы показать как я ее понимаю, исправте пожалуйста если я в чем то ошибся. Прикрепляю скрин задания на всякий случай.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Calculator { // создание класса
public double CalcFraction1 (double x, double y)  { // создание метода 
    var numerator = Math.Abs(x) - Math.Abs(y); // вычисляем числитель
    var denominator = (1 + Math.Abs(x) * Math.Abs(y)); // вычисляем знаменатель
    if (denominator == 0)   { // если знаменатель 0, то обрабатываем исключение
        throw new DivideByZeroException();
    }
    return numerator / denominator; // возвращаем результат деления
}

public static double ReadNumber ()  { 
    double value; // тип переменной 
    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)) { }  // ВОТ ТУТ ВООБЩЕ НЕ ПОНЯЛ
    return value; // возвращаем значение переменной
}
void Main () { 
    var calculator = new Calculator(); // создаем экземпляр класса Calculator
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter two numbers"); // введите два числа
    var x = ReadNumber(); 
    var y = ReadNumber();

    try  {
        Console.WriteLine($"W = {calculator.CalcFraction1(x, y)}"); // ВОТ ТУТ ВООБЩЕ НЕ ПОНЯЛ
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException) {
        Console.WriteLine("Denominator is zero"); // Если возникло исключение, то выводим на экран
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)) { }  // ВОТ ТУТ ВООБЩЕ НЕ ПОНЯЛ
```

тоже что и

```
while (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value) == false) { }
```

пока не считает значение из консоли типа  double.

Метод Double.TryParse Преобразует строковое представление числа в эквивалентное ему число двойной точности с плавающей запятой. Возвращает значение, указывающее, успешно ли выполнено преобразование. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Также присваивает полученное значение `out value`

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    out double result
)

s
    Type: System.String
```

Строка, содержащая преобразуемое число.

```
result
    Type: System.Double
```

При возврате этот метод содержит число двойной точности с плавающей запятой, эквивалентное параметру s, если преобразование завершилось успешно, или нуль, если оно завершилось неудачно. Преобразование завершается неудачно, если значение параметра s равно null или String.Empty, не является числом допустимого формата или представляет число меньше MinValue или больше MaxValue. Этот параметр передается неинициализированным; любое значение, первоначально предоставленное в объекте result, будет перезаписано.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Console.WriteLine($"W = {calculator.CalcFraction1(x, y)}");
```

выполняет функцию `calculator.CalcFraction1(x, y)` и выводит в консоль (`return numerator / denominator;`)

**Интерполяция строк**

https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.5.php

Начиная с версии языка C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015) была добавлена такая функциональность, как интерполяция строк. Эта функциональность призвана заменить форматирование строк. Так, перепишем пример с выводом значений свойств объекта Person:

```
Person person = new Person { Name = "Tom", Age = 23 };

Console.WriteLine($"Имя: {person.Name}  Возраст: {person.Age}");
```

Знак доллара перед строкой указывает, что будет осуществляться интерполяция строк. Внутри строки опять же используются плейсхолдеры {...}, только внутри фигурных скобок уже можно напрямую писать те выражения, которые мы хотим вывести.

Интерполяция по сути представляет более лаконичное форматирование. При этом внутри фигурных скобок мы можем указывать не только свойства, но и различные выражения языка C#:

```
int x = 8;
int y = 7;
string result = $"{x} + {y} = {x + y}";
Console.WriteLine(result); // 8 + 7 = 15
```

Уже внутри строки можно применять форматирование. В этом случае мы можем применять все те же описатели, что и в методе Format. Например, выведем номер телефона в формате +x xxx-xxx-xx-xx:

```
long number = 19876543210;
Console.WriteLine($"{number:+# ### ### ## ##}"); // +1 987 654 32 10
```

Добавляем пространство до и после форматируемого вывода:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Имя: {person.Name, -5} Возраст: {person.Age}"); // пробелы после
Console.WriteLine($"Имя: {person.Name, 5} Возраст: {person.Age}"); // пробелы до

Вывод:

Имя: Том      Возраст: 23
Имя:      Том Возраст: 23
```

**Добавлено**

**Вот пример работы (у меня работает)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ codename0082016 `while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)) { } `    Если введен double, то значение помещается в value, если не double, то исключение ? `Console.WriteLine($"W = {calculator.CalcFraction1(x, y)}");` В переменную calculator помещается результат функции CalcFraction1 и выводит в консоль. Так?

Comment: calculator объект класса Сalculator  а не переменная. думаю что ничего в него не помещается. это ссылка на класс.

Comment: @ codename0082016 `Console.WriteLine($"W = {calculator.CalcFraction1(x, y)}");` тогда вероятно ее можно прочитать так, "Вызвать функцию CalcFraction из класса calculator"

Comment: да..............

Comment: `while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)) { }` Если введен double, то значение помещается в value, если не double, то исключение ?

Comment: считывает до тех пор  пока не  будет введено число (целое или другое) которое может быть преобразовано в double. Либо если есть текст или не преобразовывается то повторить считывание.

Comment: при вводе буквы сразу исключение `Необработанное исключение: System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.`

Comment: странно. у меня нету исключения

Comment: исключение на какой строке?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/gs4hQ8fl3Kvko7 у меня нет исключения

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev Есть две группы методов: `type type.Parse(string)` - бросает исключение при неудаче и `bool type.TryParse(string, out type)` - вместо исключения возвращает false при неудаче.

Comment: @codename0082016 ругается на 11 строку. [Ссылка на Яндекс. Диск, код в шапке темы](http://yadi.sk/i/Ot-9sRYL3KxhmZ)

Comment: какая 11? ты скачал мой проект?

Comment: @codename0082016 ошибка была в том, что писал вместо     `static void Main () ` просто `void Main ()`. Зачем в своем коде ты используешься `while (true)` 36 строка?

Comment: чтобы бесконечно повторялось